# Lower bound for expectation of maximum of Gaussian variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,...,X_N$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variables. Prove that 
$$\mathbb{E}\max_{i\le N}X_i \ge c \sqrt{\log{N}}.$$

Attempt: For individual Guassian variable $X$, we have tail bound
$$\mathbb{P}(X\ge 0.1\sqrt{\log{N}})\ge (\frac{10}{\sqrt{\log{N}}}-(\frac{10}{\sqrt{\log{N}}})^3)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\frac{1}{N})^{0.005}.$$
RHS decreases very slowly with $N$: for large $N$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(X\ge 0.1\sqrt{\log{N}})\ge\frac{1}{N}.$$

Then apply Markov inequality, for sufficiently large $N$ (say $N>M_0$),
$$\mathbb{E}\max_{i\le N}X_i \ge 0.1\sqrt{\log{N}} \mathbb{P}(\max_{i\le N}X_i\ge 0.1\sqrt{\log{N}})$$
$$=0.1\sqrt{\log{N}} (1-\prod_{i=1}^N \mathbb{P}(X_i< 0.1\sqrt{\log{N}}))$$
$$=0.1\sqrt{\log{N}} (1-\bigg(1- \mathbb{P}(X_i\ge 0.1\sqrt{\log{N}})\bigg)^N)$$
$$\ge 0.1\sqrt{\log{N}} (1-\bigg(1- \frac{1}{N}\bigg)^N)$$
$$>0.01\sqrt{\log{N}}$$

In the case $N\le M_0,$ we just need to show that the expectation is positive and find a very small $c$.